# Post into a textarea and then get the result from another textarea

Tags: php, jquery, curl

Let say I have this JS code:

```
function plus2(){
    print (2+2);
};
```

So I want to post this code into **textarea#input** at http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ and then get the result back from **textarea#output**.

Can use PHP Curl, Shell Curl or JQuery to do the job?

P.S.: By the way, there is bug in PHP Packer port and that's whay I am not using it.

Comment: ahh much clearer question now

Comment: I am trying to simplify it a bit more, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP implementation of JSMin](https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php/) works well for me. Also, if you have server-side JS interpreter you can use [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), it's fast and provides a good compression.

Comment: Well, that'a not really what I asked.

Comment: @Roger The answer to your question is no. It's impossible. There's no such thing as posting to textarea, you can only post to a URL. And this is not how that page works anyway, it works on the client. Even works without internet connection. But as far as I understand what you actually need is a replacement for a broken PHP implementation, and I proposed just that, another well-tried packer written in PHP.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, for I made my question wrongly. It is only possible to post to an url. Period. And, it is not possible to get the content of a specific textarea once the post was made. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. It would need to be passed to a JavaScript engine at some point, so PHP/cURL is not going to be enough.

I recommend using [an alternative server-side implementation of packer](http://dean.edwards.name/download/#packer), or perhaps even [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).